# Building a form with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building a small inventory system, and would like to have a drop down menu for the user to select a part, and then enter the amount of the part. I will fill the drop down menu with elements from a mySQL database. I am familiar with mySQL, not so much with php and html, however I do program in java, so I have some coding experience. Anyway, here is the code, my current issue is that other items are just not appearing in the drop down menu.

Any other advice on the code in general would be awesome, thanks!

Code:

```
    <html>
<body>


    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <select> 
            <!-- php code to get all items -->
            <?php

                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "inventory");

                if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
                    echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_names";
                echo $sql;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    echo '<option value="$row[name]"> $row[name] </option>';

                }
            ?>

            <option value="laptop"> Laptop </option>
            <option value="ipad"> iPad </option> 
        </select>

        Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" size="5" />

        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />

    </form>


    <form action="new.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="New..." />
    </form>

    <br><br><br><br><br>

    <h3> Inventory: </h3>
    <table border="1">
    <!-- php code to fill table -->
        <tr>
            <td>(0, 0)</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(1, 0)</td>
        <tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: `mysql`, `mysqli` - what library are you using, huh?

Comment: Remove that `echo $sql`. And there is an answer down there for correct echo in while.

Comment: Probably unwise to be mixing mysqli_ and mysql_.  I also recommend separating your html and your php as many questions on this site relate to coding errors caused by jumbled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           <?php

            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "inventory");

            if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
                echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_names";
            $result=mysqli_query($sql); // not executing this
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $name=$row["name"];
                echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'. $name .'</option>';

            }
        ?>
```

actually you are not running the `mysqli_query` on the sql and try to not mixup both `mysql` and `mysqli` functions

Answer (score 1):

1. Mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions.
2. No need to `echo $sql`.
3. Strings that are built with single quotes are not parsed and vars in this strings will not be discovered. Use double quotes with proper escaping or concatenation.
4. Accessing array keys without quotes (`$row[name]`) is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this maybe?

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">' .$row['name']. '</option>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <select> 
            <!-- php code to get all items -->
            <?php

                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "inventory");

                if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
                    echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_names";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo '<option value="$row[name]"> $row[name] </option>';

                }
            ?>

            <option value="laptop"> Laptop </option>
            <option value="ipad"> iPad </option> 
        </select>

        Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" size="5" />

        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />

    </form>


    <form action="new.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="New..." />
    </form>

    <br><br><br><br><br>

    <h3> Inventory: </h3>
    <table border="1">
    <!-- php code to fill table -->
        <tr>
            <td>(0, 0)</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(1, 0)</td>
        <tr>
    </table>

</body>
```